# Does packet forwarding work on Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, networking

I've followed the instructions in this ServerFault answer https://serverfault.com/a/929086/1653 but my pings aren't getting forwarded to the destination host as expected.

I've got `IPEnableRouter` set to `1` and the Routing and Remote Access service started.

Does packet forwarding work on Windows 10 or is it crippled?

I'm running Win 10 1809 (Build 17763.1577)

Comment: What's your network look like and what/where you would like to forward? And why don't you update to the latest Windows version?

Comment: It's a corporate laptop so I can't update the Windows version. The laptop has Cisco AnyConnect VPN client running on it. I want to be able to route onto the VPN from another computer. I've gout my static routes set up as per a few guides I've read around the topic but it's just not working, hence the question about if RRAS is cripple on non-server Windows SKUs.

Comment: Perhaps including the routes in your post will help get an answer.

Comment: I'm not asking if my routes are right.  I'm asking if anyone else has got routing working on Windows 10 via the `IPEnableRouter ` registry key, so I can see if I'm barking up the wrong tree or not.

Comment: It's [cited](http://woshub.com/hyper-v-enable-routing/) as working in August 2, 2021.

Comment: The OP on that post is on Windows Server 2008 R2 which is a Server SKU. My question is does it work on Windows 10?